# SQL GET COLUMN1,MAX(AVG) as COLUMN2

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, average

here is my table :

```
ID  NAME        FNAME      CITY     SALARY
-----------------------------------------
1   Delicat     Antoine    Paris    21000
2   Rabago      Sylvain    Toulouse 21000
3   Dupont      Patrick    Nice     18000
4   Aristides   Hector     Paris    17000
5   Ramaji      Jordan     Toulouse 19000
6   Droda       Erika      Paris    18000
7   Pernelle    Emilie     Nice     17000
8   Laourd      Raoul      Lyon     15000
9   Alesi       Jean       Nice     18000
10  Straud      Amandine   Paris    20000
```

I need to display the city who have the max average salary.
I can display AVG per city :

```
SELECT CITY, AVG(SALARY) as avg_salary
FROM PILOTE
GROUP BY CITY
```

```
CITY     avg_salary
-----------------
Lyon        15000
Nice        17666
Paris       19000
Toulouse    20000
```

And i can display the max average salary :

```
SELECT MAX(AVG_SALARY) as MAX
FROM (SELECT CITY, AVG(SALARY) as AVG_SALARY
FROM PILOTE
GROUP BY CITY ) as tmp
```

```
MAX
------
20000
```

But i need to display the **max avg salary AND the city** and i don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TOP 1` with `Order by` to get the `City` with `max` Average `Salary`

```
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, AVG(SALARY) as AVG_SALARY
FROM PILOTE
GROUP BY CITY
ORDER BY AVG_SALARY DESC
```

or Use `Row_number` window Function

```
select CITY,AVG_SALARY
(
SELECT Row_number()over(order by AVG(SALARY) Desc) as RN,CITY, AVG(SALARY) as avg_salary
FROM PILOTE
GROUP BY CITY
) A
Where RN =1
```

Comment: Thanks for your speed answer, but I know this solution :/ there is no other solution as use an inner subquery ?

Comment: @user3154849 - Then use the `Row_Number` answer

Comment: There is no way to use MAX function in this case ?

Comment: @user3154849 - Why you need to use `MAX` function. This is the better of doing it.

Comment: Okay i was thinking that function MAX could be more optimized.
Thanks for your help :).